# Extract list of objects from a string using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq. I have a string having the following format

```
code:description;code2:description2;code3:description3... etc.
```

Records are separated with `;` character and each record has 2 fields separated with `:` character.

I'm writing a linq query to extract a list of objects having as fields code and description.
I have written the following query which seems to produce correct results, but I was wondering if there is a better or more correct way to do it.

```
var objects =
    from objString in recsString.Split(';')
    let obj = objString.Split(':')
    select new {
        Code = obj[0].Trim(),
        Description = obj[1].Trim()
    };
```

Comment: Is your "object" defined as its own class somewhere in your project.  If so, you could call a constructor in your select statement.  IE - select new Record(code, description);

Comment: No it's anonymous, I will create a class if I see I need it, but for now it's enough.

Comment: This will not work if you have `:` or `;` in code or description, or if any entry is empty or half-empty. Other than that its fine.

Comment: @DavidS. Fortunately there are not such cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's perfectly fine, the only observation I would make though is that you remove empty entries by using the [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx):

```
var objects =
from objString in recsString.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
let obj = objString.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
select new {
    Code = obj[0].Trim(),
    Description = obj[1].Trim()
};
```

If you think that there could be missing information, you could also be *extra safe* and `null` check the results:

```
var objects =
from objString in recsString.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
let obj = objString.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
select new {
    Code = obj.Any() ? obj[0].Trim() : string.Empty,
    Description = obj.Count > 1 ? obj[1].Trim() : string.Empty
};
```

Comment: Ok then! Thanks for the extra recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is just fine, here is how you'd write it using lambdas:

```
string objString = "code:description;code2:description2;code3:description3";

Dictionary<string, string> results =
    objString.Split(';')
             .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
             .ToDictionary(key => key[0], value => value[1]);

// And now you have a nice little dictionary
foreach (var r in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",r.Key, r.Value);
```

Or of course:

```
    var results = objString.Split(';')
                           .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                           .Select(x => new {Code = x[0], Description = x[1]});

    foreach (var r in results)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",r.Code, r.Description);
```

Comment: Nice approach. Objects list suits better my needs for now.

Comment: Sure, I though a different prospective might be useful :)